# /* rather than * in XPath selector predicate

Tags: xpath

I read somewhere previously but I am not able to provide now an explanation to this issue, so I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

I am creating XPath selectors for canonical XPaths for HTML docs. A simple example is below (enclosed in HTMLUnit which uses xalan on its background, but can be any XPath processor).

If I run:

```
WebClient webClient = ......;
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.slideshare.com/");
System.out.println(page.getByXPath("/html/body/footer/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[2]/a[*]/text()"));
```

I get a [] response. However, if I run instead (mind the a[ * ] vs a[ /* ]:

```
WebClient webClient = ......;
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.slideshare.com/");
System.out.println(page.getByXPath("/html/body/footer/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[2]/a[/*]/text()"));
```

I get [Developers Section] as response.

Is possible in a position predicate to add a wildcard as argument (i.e. [ * ]). However, for some nodes/tags (I noticed particularly with text nodes as h1, h2..., p, b, strong and with some other html tags as li or ul) sometimes a slash is required preceding the wildcard (i.e. [ /* ]) to get results.

Can someone please provide a background about what does this mean? I am unable to find a reference to this on web or in XPath spec.

Comment: as amendment, consider also the case of wildcard position predicates in intermediary tags as e.g. /html/body/footer/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul[ * ]/li[ * ]/a[ /* ]/text(). It works, not problem. My only question is that sometimes I must use /* and sometimes * and I can not provide a rationale on when and why. I need to understand in order to automatize programmatically

Comment: The rationale is that `[*]` is not a wildcard for "any index". It means "has a child element", and since your `a`s have no child elements, `a[*]` will cause the selection to turn up empty. `[/*]` means "is in a document with a root element", which is always true and therefore redundant.

Comment: so it is taking it as a boolean predicate, is not it? Yes I thought it was the wildcard for any index

Comment: Yes, the square brackets `[ ]` mean that the expression within them is taken as a boolean predicate. If the expression inside yields a node set (as `*` does), then the predicate is true iff the node set is not empty (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean).

Answer (score 1):

If your intent in using a "wildcard" is simply to select any `a` that occurs under the path `/html/body/footer/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[2]`, then you don't need a predicate at all. You can just do this:

```
/html/body/footer/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[2]/a
```

This will select *all* `a` elements that are children of the path `/html/body/footer/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[2]`.

Comment: What you say does not work for an element in the middle of the XPath selector. It would take .../a/... as .../a[1]/... for example in  /html/body/footer/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/a/div[1]/b and I want all siblings, i.e. .../a[ * ]/...

Comment: @pellyadolfo That's not correct. `/a/...` selects all `a` elements at that portion of the path and is not equivalent to `a[1]`.

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/3f52a14e-8bc3-4e58-b3b5-e340b3db83c8

Comment: Well, thanks, yes, it looks an option. I was trying the asterisk syntax since it is programmatically easier but I can reconsider. However, your good example shows how a[ /* ] has 2 results and a[ * ] finds nothing.

Comment: By programmatic reasons, I think using a syntax as .../a[1=1]/... can be easier to parse since the problem reduces to manipulate what is inside [...]. Or also .../a[.]/... is not it?

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do?  what are you using a predicate on a *for*?

as far as i can tell `a[*]` is selecting `a` with child <strike>nodes</strike> elements (see comment - thanks), and so is failing because there is no child element (similarly for `h1`, `h2`..., `p`, `b`).

in comparison, `a[/*]` is selecting any `a` below the root (more accurately, in any document that has a root - again, see comments).  which is true for all nodes, but is completely pointless.

i think you should just use `/html/body/footer/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[2]/a/text()`

[update:] a path can be "ambiguous", matching multiple things, and will return a set of results.  you don't need to do anything special (like use `[*]`) to do this.  all that `[...]` does is add *additional* constraints.  it makes things *more* specific.  you don't need anything to make things less specific - the default is to be as general as possible.

Comment: More specifically, `a[*]` is testing whether the a element has a child *element* (a child text node will not satisfy the predicate). And `a[/*]` is testing whether the `a` element appears in a document that contains a root element - which it obviously does.

Comment: What I try to do is selecting all siblings: /html/body/footer/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[2]/a[1]/text() and /html/body/footer/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[2]/a[2]/text() and /html/body/footer/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/ul/li[2]/a[3]/text() and so on. All those having an element in the document. I noticed that, for some tags * is the way to go and for some other tags /* is the way to go (agree that looks a text nodes issue).

Comment: I do not think a[ /* ] is selecting any a below the root in the whole document. With /* it works for a's. It just selects the right ones at the specified path. If I do as you say, I will not be using a wildcard and would need a different XPath per element. I am looking for a wildcard canonical XPath.

Comment: @pellyadolfo The portions in `[brackets]` are not simply indices, and `*` is not a "wildcard" meaning "any number". Michael Kay knows what he's talking about. Using `[/*]` is completely redundant and you will get exactly the same result by omitting it altogether. Have you tried it, or are you simply refusing to entertain the possibility that we might be right?

Comment: so the proper syntax to select all a's is using a flat 'a' with not [ ] as it contains a boolean predicate, not a wildcard index. Yes you are correct. Was my misunderstanding. Thanks. (Programmatically is a bit more tricky anyway).

Comment: I am thinking of using as 'select all indices' syntax with [ ] the following -> .../a[.]/... rather than flat 'a'. It will allow programmatic parsing to pay attention only on the content of [ ] rather than in dealing with syntax, and using '.' for 'current element' looks to be always true for ANY HTML tag. Do you agree that .../a[.]/.... can work the same as .../a/...?

Comment: @pellyadolfo Yes, a[.] will work, but again, it's redundant and unnecessary and I've never seen anyone write XPath like that. Unless you yourself are planning to be parsing the XPath, I don't think the XPath parser needs any "help" by being provided needless predicates.

Comment: @pellyadolfo i think you are adding documentation so that your old self would understand (which in general is good).  but your old self no longer exists - you know the standard way now... and this mistake is not common, so your `[.]` is more likely to confuse others than help.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I do not mind if anyone else is writing XPath like that. I was looking for a way to programmatically parse and manipulate paths without worrying about syntax, a way to standardize/homogenize the syntax. Thank you all.